# how to ignore the values before and after between the rows in a table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table as like below

[image]

I have to add a new column to the table as "value_", which should contains age values for rows between last TRUE i.e row number 4 (highlighted in green color) value and last record(which has 01-01-9999) and remaining all should be "zero"

like as below
[image]

If all values (except last record which have 01-01-9999) are FALSE then we need all the age values like as below
[image]

how to achieve this in sql? Could you please help me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly , here is one way:

```
SELECT * , CASE WHEN maxtrueflag IS NULL THEN age_
            CASE WHEN maxtrueflag IS NOT NULL AND from_>= maxtruefalg THEN age_ 
            ELSE 0 END AS value_
FROM (
    SELECT *, MAX(CASE WHEN flag = TRUE THEN from_ END) OVER() maxtrueflag
    FROM  tableName 
    ) t
```

Comment: If there are more than one TRUE value then we should consider records after last true value (based on order by from_) and records before last record (which contains 01-01-9999)

Comment: @kalyan4uonly well this query does what you just explained. what is the issue? am I  missing something